# how to search and retrieve the matching word from a comma separated string in one column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a problem with my `Bus` table which contain:

```
Bus_no(int)
Bus_Route(Varchar)
Bus_Stop(varchar)
```

My `Bus_Stop` column contains stop as comma separated string as given below:

```
'Apsara,Shahadara,Shakarpur,Mother Dairy,Badarpur,'
```

I need to search for a particular word like `Shakarpur` without comma in `SQL Server`.

Comment: You may have to explain the schema of the table as well as the code/queries that you have already tried.

Comment: i tried various query but they didn't gave desired value they returning the whole Bus_stop Column. but i need only matching string from it.

Comment: If possible, re-think your schema. There are data types *designed* for holding multiple values - and a string isn't one of them.Ideally, each stop would be listed as a separate row of a table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the just the match then check and select that const:

```
select BusNo, 
       BusRoute, 
       case when BusStop = 'Shakarpur' or 
                 BusStop like 'Shakarpur,%' or
                 BusStop like '%,Shakarpur,%' or
                 BusStop like '%,Shakarpur'
            then 'Shakarpur' end as BusStop
from Bus
```

If you have a parameter then:

```
select BusNo, 
       BusRoute, 
       case when BusStop = @p or 
                 BusStop like @p + ',%' or
                 BusStop like '%,' + @p + ',%' or
                 BusStop like '%,' + @p
            then @p end as BusStop
from Bus
```

**EDIT:**

Here is solution for part matching:

```
DECLARE @t TABLE
    (
      Bus_no INT ,
      Bus_Route VARCHAR(20) ,
      Bus_Stop VARCHAR(200)
    )
INSERT  INTO @t
VALUES  ( 1, '1', 'Apsara,Shahadara,Shakarpur,Mother Dairy,Badarpur' ),
        ( 2, '2', 'Amsterdam,Brussels,Bruges,Brussels,London,Liverpool' ),
        ( 3, '3', 'k,k,k' );


;WITH cte AS(SELECT  Bus_no ,
                     Bus_Route ,
                     Split.a.value('.', 'VARCHAR(100)') Bus_Stop
FROM    ( SELECT    Bus_no ,
                    Bus_Route ,
                    CAST ('<M>' + REPLACE(Bus_Stop, ',', '</M><M>') + '</M>' AS XML) AS Data
          FROM      @t
        ) AS t
        CROSS APPLY Data.nodes('/M') AS Split ( a ))

SELECT Bus_no, 
       Bus_Route,
       STUFF((Select  ',' + c2.Bus_Stop
              From cte c2
              Where c1.Bus_no = c2.Bus_no AND Bus_Stop LIKE '%s%'
              For XML PATH ('')), 1, 1, '') Bus_Stop
FROM cte c1
WHERE Bus_Stop LIKE '%s%'
GROUP BY Bus_no, Bus_Route
```

Output:

```
Bus_no  Bus_Route   Bus_Stop
1       1           Apsara,Shahadara,Shakarpur
2       2           Amsterdam,Brussels,Bruges,Brussels
```

Comment: `BusStop like 'Shakarpur,%' OR BusStop like '%,Shakarpur,%'` would be better. This will not return results like `'Shakarpuri'`

Comment: I do not want to match it only  i want to retrieve it too.

Comment: @GiorgiNakeuri Thanks but it returns null untill i write the whole word cam please make it so that it can give matching results.

Comment: @MurlidharThakur, your question didn't mention it. May be you better add that useful information to your question?

Comment: @GiorgiNakeuri  Thanks but can u please make it character matching pattern so that when i write one character then it should return the values which matches with it.